# Граница графика (Flot)

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Делаю график на jQuery, при помощи библиотеки Flot. Подскажите, есть ли возможность убрать border графика, например, снизу и сверху. Делал как в [api](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md), но не помогает.

Comment: Приведите пример, как вы пробовали убрать бордеры.

Answer (score 1):

точно не помню. там среди свойств посмотреть надо

```
 plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
                      [ 
                        { data: a, label: "cos(x) = -0.00" } ], {
                            series: {
                                lines: { show: true }
                            },
                            crosshair: { mode: "x" },
                            grid: { hoverable: true, autoHighlight: false },
                            yaxis: { min: 450, max: 600},
                            xaxis: { min: 0, max: 49}
                        });
```